# Different color for sorting in SSRS

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a customer who would like some color formatting in an SSRS report.  I cannot utilize grouping due to the customer requirements.  I have the report sorting by `Main Tank` and would like the sorts to alternate in color.  So it would have several rows of `Tank A` all be grey then several rows of `Tank B` all be white.  I'm using this currently but it only works on the first row of each sort

`=iif(
Fields!Tank.Value=previous(Fields!Tank.Value),
"Transparent",
"Red"
)`

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom code to get the required logic. Using a custom function in your code that returns the color based on the the Tank value.

Go to `Report` menu, `Report Properties` / `Code` tab and in the text area put this code:

```
Dim prevColor As String = "Transparent"
Public Function GetColor(ByVal flag As Integer) As String
  If flag = 1 Then
    If prevColor = "Transparent" Then
      prevColor = "Gray"
    Else
      prevColor = "Transparent"
    End If
  End If
  Return prevColor
End Function
```

Now in the cell background-color property use this expression:

```
=Code.GetColor(iif(Fields!Tank.Value=previous(Fields!Tank.Value),0,1))
```

It will color the background as below:

[image]

**UPDATE:** The above logic colors correctly only the first, third, fifth columns and so on. It is caused by multiple calls to the `GetColor` function and overwritting of the global variable `prevColor`.

I managed to solve that issue by passing the row number to the function. This is the updated function:

```
Dim prevColor As String = "Transparent"
Dim rowNum As Integer = 0
Public Function GetColor(ByVal flag As Integer, ByVal nRow As Integer) As String
  If flag = 1 And rowNum <> nRow Then
    If prevColor = "Transparent" Then
      prevColor = "Gray"
    Else
      prevColor = "Transparent"
    End If
  End If
  rowNum = nRow
  Return prevColor
End Function
```

Note the function receives a new argument so the expression for calling has changed:

```
=Code.GetColor(iif(Fields!Tank.Value=previous(Fields!Tank.Value),0,1),
RowNumber("DataSet3"))
```

> Replace `"DataSet3"` by the actual name of your dataset.

It should generate the following tablix:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This worked when I applied it to the entire row but I have several columns with a custom fill expression based on other variables so I have to put the expression you gave into the columns that i specifically want to shade.  Problem is it only does every other column with your code.

Comment: I don't get what you mean entirely, it will work only for one column, is it your issue?

Comment: I cant link pictures yet but it will work for column A, all the formatting and color will be correct.  Column B will have NO color at all.  Column C will have correct color.  Column D will have NO color at all.  And yes I have double checked that columns B and D have the proper expression in the fill section.

Comment: @Aerobane , Initially I thought you wanted to color one column. The function colored correctly only the first column. Now you can achieve the desired result using the update function.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle this in your query by adding a column that returns a 0 or 1 to define the color - idea sketch: use rank to get numbers that correlate to the sort order and then use MOD 2 to get a 0 or 1.  If you post a sample query, we can help figure out the specifics.